# Convert this sql command to c# linq

Tags: linq, t-sql, code-conversion

I am trying to convert this tSql command to linq query.
I want to group this columns.
Can you help me?

```
select  vUnit.FK_Unit_ID , Unit.unitNumber, unit.unitTitle , title.featureTitleName
from unit.UnitFeatureValue vUnit
inner join unit.Unit on vUnit.FK_Unit_ID = Unit.ID
inner join unit.FeatureTitle title on vUnit.FK_FeatureTitle_ID = title.ID
where vUnit.FK_Unit_ID = 15 and title.canMoreSelect = 1
group by vUnit.FK_Unit_ID ,unit.unitNumber, unit.unitTitle , title.featureTitleName
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: what is the goal of your **group by**, you don't have a count or a sum or anything like that

Comment: from the query it's being used as a `select distrinct`

Comment: How to convert var query result to my class?

Comment: use your class `new YourClass {...}` instead of just `new {...}`

Comment: yes i can convert var result to my class. :). with query.First() i can get field name. thanks again Matthew Whited.

Comment: "[Why is can someone help me not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (
    from v in dbContext.UnitFeatureValue
    join u in dbContext.Unit on v.FK_Unit_ID equals u.ID
    join t in dbContext.FeatureTitle on v.FK_FeatureTitle_ID equals t.ID
    where v.FK_Unit_ID == 15 && t.canMoreSelect == 1
    select  new {
        v.FK_Unit_ID, 
        u.unitNumber, 
        u.unitTitle, 
        t.featureTitleName,
    }).Distinct();
```

Comment: When the SQL has table aliases such as `vUnit` and `title` I recommend using them as the range variables.

Comment: I would recomend not making this mess at all.

Comment: That sounds like saying "I would recommend not programming"? Why are you on this site? If you think you have a better approach, shouldn't your answer reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
var result = (from v in vUnit 
join u in unit on v.FK_Unit_ID equals u.ID
join t in title on v.FK_FeatureTitle_ID equals t.ID
where v.FK_Unit_ID == 15 and t.canMoreSelect == 1
select new { v.FK_Unit_ID , u.unitNumber, u.unitTitle , t.featureTitleName }).ToList();
```

Comment: explain the downvote please, and propose something better?

Comment: your join syntax is wrong and this will not do the distinct/grouping

Comment: did you see the original query? does it need a group by?

Comment: That would depend on the data.  but your join syntax is stil wrong.  `=` should be `equals` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Comment: (just as a note `=` should be `==` on the where clause and the `(`...`).ToList()` isn't needed.  (And kills composability)